# How to Enable Java EE in Apache Netbeans IDE 10

Tags: java, netbeans

I downloaded the final version of Apache Netbeans 10.0 on the [official website](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb100/nb100.html), however I can not enable Java EE, I go into the IDE Plugin itself, but the option to download does not appear.

[image: New Project]

Comment: Have you tried to download the Java EE installer from Oracle?

Comment: But how to enable Java EE in Netbeans projects?

Comment: You have to install Java EE before you enable it.  Have you installed Java 10 EE?

Comment: Hello @Ramhound, my friend, thanks for your support, but I got a solution, I do not know if it is the most appropriate, but it worked right at this [Dzone](https://dzone.com/articles/notes-on-java-eejakarta-ee-support-for-netbeans-9) , it demonstrates how to enable Java EE in Netbeans 10 or 9, using the Netbeans 8.2 Plugin. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should submit an answer with detailed instructions on what you did to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable Java EE in Netbeans 10, through the Netbeans 8.2 update center, to add it just go to: `Tools> Plugins> Settings`.
Then, add a new update repository:

http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/8.2/uc/final/distribution/catalog.xml.gz

[image: repository]

[image: plugins]

Now look for new plugins with the keyword "Kit". As the name suggests, **these are collections of plugins for specific purposes**, these being suggestive: HTML5 Kit, JSF, SOAP Web Services, EJB and EAR, RESTful Web Services and **Java EE Base**.

[image: plugins]

To conclude, just restart the IDE and then Java EE is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to follow Anderson Marques Neto procedure without succeding.

Instead i just tried to create a web project from scratch, and netbeans guided me to the installation of the missing plugin from there on.

Running version 11.1